# N times per day we exhibit 10% loss for indefinite minutes, sometimes hours

Tags: networking, linux-networking

We are managing like 350 servers, in couple of different cabinets. Sometimes for a certain period of time we lost 10% of pings and session drops with a whole cabin. It is obivous that there is no problem with servers because problem starts with all servers within the cabinet at the same time and ends again at the same time. (We are monitoring servers with a dedicated server in one those cabinets)

In addition to this we read 80 mbits of traffic which we believe is not natural. But interestingly after midnight when traffic should be around 20 mbits, we read 80 mbits when this problem occur, and in the mid day we read 80 mbits again when this problem occur when normal traffic should be around 60 mbits.

[image: 80Mbit reads are those times when we have ping problem]

DC says that there is no problem with their router, switch etc. They say that servers have problem but when we check servers, loads are close to 0 or 0.5.

So we are stuck with this, they dont accept or even comment about this problem. We really need at least a comment about it and we believe that this is the true place for this question. Hope you even comment about it.

Update (15 of July); Now DC told me that (I dont know how stupid explanation is that) the cable MAY be connected to 100 MBit port. I dont know if any 100 Mbit ports left in any DC but that is their explanation. Here is the new graph;

[image: Latest graph, problem occured for 2 hours]

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have a switch inside your cabinet?  Perhaps *your* switch is going bad?

Comment: Yes we do have, 2 switches for internal and external use. We suspect from that also but DC provided us that and they say anything about it.

Comment: I had a problem with intermittent packet loss due to a bad netgear gigabit switch.  But that wouldn't explain the unexpected traffic.  I wonder if 'inbound' is really in or outbound in this case?  Perhaps one or more of your servers is hacked /open relay and sending spam or whatnot.

Comment: @user16081 I really dont think about hacking because the problem starts with all servers and end at the same time. Unexpected traffic is the most interesting point in this problem which confuses us.

Comment: You may want to elaborate by replacing "Sometimes for a certain period of time..." with "N times per day we exhibit n% loss for n seconds."  On each occurrence, are you losing connectivity for 5 seconds or five minutes?  Does it occur three times per day or thirty times per day?  Does the symptom manifest from multiple remote locations or only one?

Comment: @GregAskew You are right I guess, I did not provide good info. I have changed and updated the question. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that one of the devices connected to your rack switch has a bad NIC that intermittently becomes chatty (and floods the segment with garbage).  Alternatively, it's possible that there may be a problem with the switch in spite of what the datacentre operators say, and it might also be possible that you have a bad cable.

If possible, at the time that high packet loss occurs, check the lights on the switch.  Most switches will indicate an abnormality caused by a faulty NIC sending garbled traffic (though the way in which they do this varies widely, usually the light that indicates a connection will flash or something, but in any case it will be the odd one out).

There might also be something else flooding lots of traffic; consider running tcpdump or something to see if there is a likely DoS going on.  Dropping packets during network congestion is normal behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Falcon, I will check on NIC problem ASAP. Hope it is the answer because we are having really bad time with this.

Comment: if you can get a second switch and can have 2 switches at the same time, move half the devices to the new switch and see if the problem happens on both or just the existing one.